# Обрезка картинок в папке средствами php

Tags: php, изображения

Есть папка с 6000+ картинками. Они все разного размера, их нужно порезать под квадрат. Квадрат вырезать из центра, со стороной, равной меньшей стороне исходного прямоугольника.
Как вырезать квадрат средствами PHP, я знаю.
А вот как перебрать все картинки по одной в папке? И сколько времени займёт работа такого скрипта (перебор + обрезание)? Размер исходной картинки не более 100 кб.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, у кого опыт есть? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Получаешь список файлов в дирректории

```
$files = scandir( '/home/username/images );
```

Потом проходишься `foreach`'ем по этому списку и пробуешь открывать их при помощи `imagick` или `gd`. Кто выкинул исключение, того пропускаем, остальных режем. Или можно ещё имя файла проверять на расширение. Как-то так.